# (python) list of datetime to string

Tags: python, datetime

- **working on list of datetime to string**

most of the examples used`datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2005', '%b %d %Y').date()`
[Convert string "Jun 1 2005 1:33PM" into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/convert-string-jun-1-2005-133pm-into-datetime)
which can only put one one input at a time, but I am reciving the entire string  such as

```
customer_date_list = ['2011-06-2', '2011-08-05', '2011-02-04', '2010-01-14', '2010-12-13', '2010-01-12', '2010-2-11', '2010-02-07', '2010-12-02', '2011-11-30']
```

my expect output is

```
['2010-01-12', '2010-01-14', '2010-02-07', '2010-02-11', '2010-12-02', '2010-12-13', '2011-02-04', '2011-06-02', '2011-08-05', '2011-11-30']
```

the code below:
I'm making either of those code work:

```
list1_date_string = [datetime.strftime(fs, "%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M") for fs in list1_date] 
      
dateStr = list1_date.strftime("%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M")
```

- **the overall code**

```js
import datetime
def date_sorting_operation(input_list):
  
  list1_date = [datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, "%Y-%m-%d") for ts in input_list] 
  for i in range(len(list1_date)):
        for i in range(len(list1_date) - 1):
            if list1_date[i] > list1_date[i + 1]:
              temporary = list1_date[i + 1]
              list1_date[i + 1] = list1_date[i]
              list1_date[i] = temporary
            
  #list1_date_string = [datetime.strftime(fs, "%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M") for fs in list1_date] 
  
  #dateStr = list1_date.strftime("%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M")
  return list1_date, type(list1_date)
                     
customer_date_list = ['2011-06-2', '2011-08-05', '2011-02-04', '2010-01-14', '2010-12-13', '2010-01-12', '2010-2-11', '2010-02-07', '2010-12-02', '2011-11-30']
print (date_sorting_operation(customer_date_list))
```

the code and output picture:
[image: the code and output picture:]

Comment: my aim is tried to sort the date as practice without using build-in function  `sort( )` , if that is there a way just convert my output date time into it? Cause I was really close, Thanks @Darshil Jani @Misho Janev @r.user.05apr for helping

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the dates by converting them to datetime objects using a lambda (inline) function and using the converted datetime objects as the key for sorting.

```
from datetime import datetime

customer_date_list = ['2011-06-2', '2011-08-05', '2011-02-04', '2010-01-14', '2010-12-13', '2010-01-12', '2010-2-11', '2010-02-07', '2010-12-02', '2011-11-30']
customer_date_list.sort(key = lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d'))
print(customer_date_list)

# output : ['2010-01-12', '2010-01-14', '2010-02-07', '2010-2-11', '2010-12-02', '2010-12-13', '2011-02-04', '2011-06-2', '2011-08-05', '2011-11-30']
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that the dates you receive are in the format YYYY-MM-DD... Why not simply sort them as strings if you just want to order them?

```
sorted(customer_date_list)
```

Would give you the output you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
from datetime import datetime

customer_date_list = ['2011-06-2', '2011-08-05', '2011-02-04', '2010-01-14', '2010-12-13', '2010-01-12', '2010-2-11', '2010-02-07', '2010-12-02', '2011-11-30']

# using only text functions
sorted(['-'.join([y.zfill(2) for y in x.split('-')]) for x in customer_date_list])

# with date conversion
sorted([datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in customer_date_list])
```